# Refund downvoters' reputation for significantly downvoted answers

Tags: feature-request, reputation, down-votes

I get that downvoting should cost reputation to prevent misuse (is there another reason?).

But if there's a significantly downvoted post, the downvoters were most likely not misusing downvoting.

Now some of these posts are eligible for deletion, and most users will delete their own significantly downvoted posts (both of which will refund your reputation), but, in some cases, they may:

- No longer be active on the site
- Feel strongly that the answer should stick around
- Have gotten some reputation out of it (e.g. `+2`/`-9` -> `-7` score -> `+2` reputation)
  Side note - it's a bit sad that a `-7` post can actually *give* you reputation

But we want these posts to get downvoted if users feel they are not useful (don't we?).

So we don't really want to demotivate downvoting these by having it cost reputation.

So I propose we refund reputation for the downvoters for these posts.

What is "significantly downvoted"? Well, to me, it would make sense to have it be the same as when the post gets greyed out, which is currently `-3`, but this is up for discussion.

Should downvotes past "significantly downvoted" no longer cost reputation either? I don't know (ben makes a good point). If it should, we could, for example, refund reputation at `-3`, but then it costs reputation for downvotes from there again (which won't get refunded). Admittedly this part may need some more thought, but it's a start.

Comment: Once such a post gets deleted, the reputation lost will be refunded. Arguably, highly downvoted posts like you describe should be deleted.

Comment: We already automatically delete certain posts based on quality (and age), so there is precedent. And I would say that Meta sites should probably have different criteria, as even highly downvoted answers have merit (in showing different points of view and the community reaction to them, if nothing else).

Answer (score 11):

Once you have, oh, 20k of rep, you won't be able to find enough answers to downvote to put a dent it in. Trust me. I've tried. While I have some sympathy for the logic of your posting, it seems to me that this is making the rep system work just as defined. People with 'some rep' are conservative in casting downvotes. People with tons of the stuff downvote whenever they see a post that deserves it. In other words, more downvotes get cast by the more experiences people.

Comment: Consider: the most you could *possibly* lose from down-voting would be 30 points per day, by using all of your votes on answers. That's... Three answer up-votes, which, if you've reached 20K, you're probably able to obtain without considerable effort. It's *supposed* to hurt just a little bit, just to make you think twice about it - frivolous down-votes annoy people unnecessarily - but practically-speaking, it's irrelevant.

Answer (score 4):

This would only encourage the dogpile effect which is one of the negative points often brought up about the site.  Making sure the casters know that they're spending their rep to do this is a good feedback mechanism to keep the dogpiling down.

Comment: The only "dogpiling" that I see is from -2 to -3. We can have votes beyond -3 cost reputation (as per last paragraph in the question) and above -2 is still risky - you will only get the reputation back if it gets to -3.